# Form with list of lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, http-post

I have been struggling with what seems to me to be a simple thing. I need to create a form with list of lists.

This is the model that I want to make a form of:

```
    public OrderViewModel()
    {
        DeliveryAddress = new ProjectDeliveryAddressViewModel();
        OrderItems = new List<OrderItemView>();
    }

    public int ProjectDeliveryId { get; set; }
    public long ProjectId { get; set; }
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Res.ViewModels.Common), Name = "CustomerOrderNumber")]
    public string CustomerOrderNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Res.ViewModels.Common), Name = "DeliveryDate")]
    public string RequestedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public ProjectDeliveryAddressViewModel DeliveryAddress { get; set; }

    public IList<OrderItemView> OrderItems { get; set; } 
}

public class OrderItemView
{
    public OrderItemView()
    {
        Additionalitems = new List<AdditionalItem>();
    }

    public long ProjectItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ImageData { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AaCompany { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public int SupplierModelId { get; set; }
    public IList<AdditionalItem> Additionalitems { get; set; } 
}

public class AdditionalItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

What is the simplest way of doing this so that I can easily post the form to my mvc controller later on?

Comment: What kind of form you using? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: html forms. <form id="blabla" name="blabla"> 
 <input type"text" />
etc etc
</form>

Comment: Sorry, I have tried this kinds of things with html little bit and they are pain. Good luck with that!

Comment: Did you solve this kinds of problems in any other way that i might use?

Comment: I guess you will need to generate HTML table dynamically.